# How to reuse functions that are invoked from within an "action" on your controllers using ember.js

Tags: ember.js

A few months back ember.js changed the scoping of "actions" that get invoked from something like a button click. For example, in the below handlebars template if I click "save"

```
<button type="submit" {{action updateModel model}}>Save</button>
```

It bubbles up to the actions on my controller like so

```
actions: {
    updateModel: function(model) {
        var name = model.get('name');
        //if I want to hit a mixin or instance method
        //I am forced to use "send" but how can I send
        //state to this method? or is this even the way
        //ember wants you to "reuse" code from within
        //an action?
    }
}
```

The problem is, if I have a complex action and I want to share code between controllers. What is the "correct" way to share even a simple "validate" like method when I'm stuck inside an "action" like this?

Comment: `this` inside actions methods is controller itself, so you can move code you want to reuse to controller itself. If you want to share code broader, use inheritance, mixins, or (in case of validation) move code to model.

Comment: The comment above seems fine. Does it answer your question? If not, you should try to explain your question in more detail.

Comment: Is this new to ember 1.3? In 1.0 I could only do something like this.send('method') instead of this.method(args) -can you confirm this works w/out the special "send"? If send is still required how can I pass args to it?

Comment: Calli controller methods from action handlers through `this.method(args)` should be possible even in 1.0. Anyway, if you need to communicate/share functionality between controllers, you can use property `needs: ['some-other-controller-name']`. Than you should be able to access such controller's methods through `this.get('controller.some-other-controller-name').method(args)` or instead of calling `method(args)` you can trigger the linked controller's actions through `send('action-name')` method. Hope this helps.